# Edit AutoCAD database, adding new tables

Tags: c#, .net, database, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm developing an AutoCAD plugin and I want to create new objects and new information.

How can I access the AutoCAD database for example adding a new table and getting information from it?

Is this possible?

Is there another way to store information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for my classes. I recommend following this site too: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/how-can-i-store-my-custom-information-in-a-dwg-file.html